# How to extract the number(0-9) from the string in informatica?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I want to extract the number(0-9) from the string. e.g.

1. if src is `*J$456*&56` then tgt should be `45656`
2. if src is `&*(>123>>789&^` then tgt should be `123789`

This is just an example, special characters or alphabets are random in string, so how to extract only numbers?

Thanks is advance.

Regards
sheetal

Comment: check REG_REPLACE in help

Comment: Thanks user2794034.....it is working:)

Answer (score 4):

You'd need to replace all other characters with an empty string. Try

```
REG_REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME, '[^0-9]', '')
```